# EventGridTrigger in Azure function - Log dependency injection not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Here is development environment version details

- **.Net Core Version** : 2.2
- **Visual Studio** : 2019

Here is the `startup.cs` class

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace PaaS.Azure.Functions
{
  public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
  {
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        builder.Services
            .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config)
            .AddSingleton(serviceProvider => serviceProvider)
            .AddLogging();
      }
  }
}
```

Here is the `EventGridTrigger` class

```
public class DataProcessingFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;
    public DataProcessingFunction(ILogger<DataProcessingFunction> log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    [FunctionName("DataProcessingFunction")]
    public void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent)
    {
            _log.LogInformation("Triggered");
    }
}
```

> Logs are not printing

But I replace `_log` with `Log` by passing ILogger, it just works

```
public void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger Log)
{
         Log.LogInformation("Triggered");
}
```

why does `ILogger<DataProcessingFunction> log` is not working?

Comment: Have you specified your logLevel in your host.json?

Comment: This should works. Same code works on my side. No need to replace.

Comment: Can not reproduce your problem, can you share the output of the Console?

Comment: @chris, no I did not specify. Is it required?

Comment: Try adding `"logging": { "logLevel": { "PaaS.Azure.Functions": "Information" } }` to your host.json file

Comment: See this https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4345 and this https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4425#issuecomment-492678381

Comment: Yes, It's in my bucket list. as soon as the testing completes will do. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 0228:**

This issue only occurs in azure portal, but can work locally. One interesting thing is that the logs are not shown in Log Console, but it does show in Log Streaming console(in azure portal -> function app -> Platform features -> Log streaming):

[image]

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

This issue is caused by the `namespace` which has the character `"."` .

If the `namespace` of azure function has the character `"."`(in your case, it's `PaaS.Azure.Functions`), then you need to specify the LogLevel like below in `host.json` file(remember that right click the `host.json` file -> select Properties -> set "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy if newer"):

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "PaaS.Azure.Functions": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can see the logs are printed out.

If the `namespace` of azure function **does not** have the character `"."`(assume the namespace is `MyFunctionApp`), then you don't need the above settings, and the logs are always printed out.

Comment: no luck. But I can see logs in "Application Insights".  This link also says same thing https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4345, thanks for the link

Comment: @kudlatiger, I tested it with a blob trigger function(does not have an event grid), I can see everything is ok anyway. Not sure why it does not work there:(.

Comment: Is it anything to do with solution name which i configured in host.json ? My solution name is "POC.PaaS.Azure.Solution"  and my project name is "PaaS.Azure.Functions"

Comment: @kudlatiger, Not sure if the solution name is the root cause. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @kudlatiger, just tested it out, it's ok if the solution name does not match the project name. Are you testing the function locally, and set the logLevel in host.json file, and the host.json file is set "Copy to Output Directory" as "Copy if newer"?

Comment: I did not test locally, I am directly testing in azure portal. let me try locally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208689/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-kudlatiger).

Comment: @kudlatiger, I updated the answer with new findings. Anyway, I'll raise an issue to MS support team and let you know if any feedback.

Comment: @IvanYang thanks for sharing. I can't tell you how many hours I've lost trying to figure this out. Your solution with the host.js worked for me.